# Why using bind is necessary in this implementation of curry function

Tags: javascript, currying

There is a curry function from https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/curry.

```
const curry = (fn, arity = fn.length, ...args) => {
  if (args.length >= arity) {
    return fn(...args)
  } else {
    return curry.bind(null, fn, arity, ...args) // line(*)
  }
}
console.log(curry(Math.pow)(2)(10)) // 1024
console.log(curry(Math.min, 3)(10)(50)(2)) // 2
```

Why using bind is necessary in line(*)? Can it be replaced with

```
return curry(fn, arity, ...args) // line(**)
```

?

Comment: `fn.bind()` always returns *a new function*. While `fn()` will *call the function*.

Comment: "*Can it be replaced with by `return curry(fn, arity, ...args)`*" [you can try it and find out](https://jsbin.com/senomax/edit?js,console)

Comment: You can replace it with `return (...args2) => curry(fn, arity, ...args, ...args2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two reasons to ever use `Function#bind`:

1. When you want to bind the function to a particular context object. Practically speaking, when you want to make sure ahead of time that the `this` keyword inside the function will refer to a particular, known object.
2. When you want to pre-define some arguments, a.k.a. "partial function application".

The second case lends itself perfectly to what function currying is all about - making an N-ary function flexibly callable like:

- `fn(arg1, arg2, ..., argN)`, or
- `fn(arg1, arg2, ...)(argN)`, or
- `fn(arg1, arg2)(..., argN)`, or
- `fn(arg1)(arg2)(...)(argN)`.

The important thing to notice here is that **we need multiple separate functions** for all cases but the first. Let's say you have a worker function that takes 3 arguments. You can...

1. ...pass enough arguments for the worker function, i.e. 3 or more. Then `curry()` calls the worker function with those 3 arguments and returns the result.
   This makes `fn(arg1, arg2, arg3)` possible.
2. ...pass too few arguments for the worker function. Then `curry()` does not call the worker, but must **return a new function** which takes the remaining number of arguments.
   This makes all of `fn(arg1)(arg2, arg3)` and `fn(arg1, arg2)(arg3)` and `fn(arg1)(arg2)(arg3)` possible.

`Function#bind` covers the second case: It creates a new wrapper function for the worker and pre-fills some of the worker's argument slots with the given values. The context object is irrelevant for that intention, so using `null` here is fine.

```
const curry = (fn, arity = fn.length, ...args) =>
    //  enough arguments ?    call     :   remember arguments so far & defer 
    args.length >= arity ? fn(...args) : curry.bind(null, fn, arity, ...args);
```

So to answer the question: No, you can't use `return curry(fn, arity, ...args)` because this does not do the most important thing, which is to create a new function.

---

**Example:** Let's say we have a worker function that searches a string and returns the number of hits.

```
const search = (str, substr) => {
    var hits = 0, pos = 0;
    while (true) {
        pos = str.indexOf(substr, pos) + 1;
        if (pos) hits++; else return hits;
    }
}
```

Now we could create a curried version that remembers the target string for us and we only need to switch the last argument:

```
const flexibleSearch = curry(search);

const reusableSearch = flexibleSearch("... a ... b ... c ... a ... b ... a");

reusableSearch("a")   // -> 3
reusableSearch("b")   // -> 2
reusableSearch("c")   // -> 1
reusableSearch("d")   // -> 0
```

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and thorough. I upvoted your answer since it is very detailed and accurate. I am still adding an answer to just simplify things.

Comment: In the context of javascript, I wonder if it is necessary to have a curry function (be it implemented by developer or from third party), when it comes natively with "bind" that can achieve the same thing as curry.

Comment: @Nick If you're going to do functional programming, `curry()` is still necessary, since `.bind()` can only produce an output function with fixed arity, whereas `curry()` gives you a flexible one.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks. Wish there is an example that illustrate the "flexible" one that bind() can't achieve.

Comment: @Nick assuming `f = (a, b, c) => {...}`, `f2 = curry(f)` produces a function that can be flexibly invoked like `f2(a, b, c)` or `f2(a, b)(c)` or `f2(a)(b)(c)`, i.e. it produces a new partial until the last argument is given. That's exactly the thing `f.bind()` cannot do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My understanding is f.bind() can do the same thing. I tested out something like this f.bind(null,"hello","world")("deal")  or f.bind(null,"hello").bind(null, "world")("deal").  All works.  But i have to admit, the function calling syntax is more verbose than the curry version.

Comment: @Nick That's not how it works. Even ignoring the primary purpose of `.bind()`, which is to _bind_ a function to a context object (here: `null`) - `.bind()` returns a new rigid ("N-ary") function `f2` that expects all its remaining arguments at once, and `.bind()` *must* pre-define arguments in order to change `f2`'s arity. `curry()` on the other hand pre-defines no arguments, and returns an `f2` with flexible arity. A curried `f2` can be called es `f2('Hello')('world')('!')` or any other argument combination. The bound function cannot. You've called `.bind()` twice yourself because it can't.

Comment: Oh think i got what u mean.  The key thing is.bind() must pre-define arguments to change f2's arity, while curry() ppre-defines no argument, return an f2 with flexible arity.  Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 0):

@Tomalak is correct

Lets say you have a function that takes 100 parameters `fn(1,2,3,...100) {}`.

`fn.bind(null, 99, 100)` creates a new function with **preset leading argument**. In our example will use the default values for parameters 1,2,...97,98 and expect two parameters as input for the new function that will be used as parameter 99, and 100.

In this case, we are **currying** a function to accept partial arguments.

You can go through these to get a deeper understanding
[Wiki for currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and
[MDN docs for binding partial functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions)